# Wrap text around an image without CSS for email?

Tags: css-float, newsletter

I have a text with a thumbnail. This image is displayed top left. The text is visible at the right and bottom sides of the image.

Inside an email, I can't use the css-float left attribute. I tried to use tables without succes. How can I show the thumbnail top left without css for inside an email?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the align attribute:

```
<img src="" align="left" /> The content that you are trying to wrap the image around
```

This will float your image to the left, the same as css float.

Comment: Well done! Did not expect a solution, but this saved my life. Thanks!